# When are scala's for-comprehensions lazy?

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation, for-comprehension

In Python, I can do something like this:

```
lazy = ((i,j) for i in range(0,10000) for j in range(0,10000))
sum((1 for i in lazy))
```

It will take a while, but the memory use is constant.

The same construct in scala:

```
(for(i<-0 to 10000; j<-i+1 to 10000) yield (i,j)).count((a:(Int,Int)) => true)
```

After a while, I get a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`, even though it should be evaluated lazily.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Nothing's inherently lazy about Scala's for-comprehension; it's syntactic sugar* which won't change the fact that the combination of your two ranges will be eager.

If you work with lazy `view`s of your ranges, the result of the comprehension will be lazy too:

```
scala> for(i<-(0 to 10000).view; j<-(i+1 to 10000).view) yield (i,j)
res0: scala.collection.SeqView[(Int, Int),Seq[_]] = SeqViewN(...)

scala> res0.count((a: (Int, Int)) => true)
res1: Int = 50005000
```

The laziness here is nothing to do with the for-comprehension, but because when `flatMap` or `map` (see below) are called on some type of container, you get back a result in the same type of container. So, the for-comprehension will just preserve the laziness (or lack of) of whatever you put in.

---

*for something like:

```
(0 to 10000).flatMap(i => (i+1 to 10000).map(j => (i, j)))
```

Comment: "something like", but the latter expression seems to return 100020001 elements, not 50005000.  Whiskey tango foxtrot?

Comment: @Malvolio thanks for noticing! `j` should have been from `i+1 to 10000`, not `1 to 10000`. Fixed now.

Comment: D'oh.  I should have noticed the solution, not just the problem.  I was staring at the map functions, ignoring the arguments..

Comment: Wasn't Int.to(Int) lazy in 2.7?

Answer (score 13):

Laziness comes not from the for-comprehension, but from the collection itself. You should look into the strictness characteristics of the collection.

But, for the lazy :-), here's a summary: `Iterator` and `Stream` are non-strict, as are selected methods of the `view` of any collection. So, if you want laziness, be sure to `.iterator`, `.view` or `.toStream` your collection first.